# Dictionary class return empty values

Tags: c#, dictionary

So, I have an example of code that I wrote.

My goal is to enter a values to a dictionary class which contain a key(string), and the value is another dictionary with key(string) and value of List.

The problem is that after I am clearing the `innerDictionary`, the values inside the `mainDictionary` are disappears.

```
            List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
            list1.Add("1");
            list1.Add("2");
            list1.Add("3");
            List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
            list2.Add("4");
            list2.Add("5");
            list2.Add("6");
            List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
            list3.Add("7");
            list3.Add("8");
            list3.Add("9");
            List<string> list4 = new List<string>();
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> mainDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> innerDictionary = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
            foreach (string s1 in list1)
            {
                foreach (string s2 in list2)
                {
                    foreach(string s3 in list3)
                    {
                        list4.Add(s3);
                    }
                    innerDictionary.Add(s2, list4);
                    list4.Clear();
                }

                mainDictionary.Add(s1, innerDictionary);
                innerDictionary.Clear();
            }
```

Comment: what language is this? did you make the `Dictionary` class?

Comment: `Add` does not *copy* the object, but stores a reference to the same object. When you `Clear`, it clears that one instance. Instead, create a `new` collection each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new dictionary and lists inside your loops

```
foreach (string s1 in list1)
{
    Dictionary<string,List<string>>() innerDictionary = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
    foreach (string s2 in list2)
    {
        List<string>() list4 = new List<string>();
        foreach(string s3 in list3)
        {
            list4.Add(s3);
        }

        innerDictionary.Add(s2, list4);
    }

    mainDictionary.Add(s1, innerDictionary);
}
```